# Error in if statement in shell script

Tags: shell, csh

I am trying to execute the following shell script

```
#!/bin/csh
if [[ $# != 1  ||  $1 != "first" && $1 != "second" ]]
then
    echo "Error: Usage: $0 [first|second]"
    exit 1
fi
```

but I am getting an error:

if: Expression Syntax.

I have no idea what's wrong with that syntax. It looks fine to me. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C shell (csh) doesn't have the variable `$#`. In fact, in csh the arguments passing, `if` statement etc are fundamentally different to say, ksh or bash. All your code looks like a bash code but your shebang line contains `csh`. So if you want to use `bash` then change it to:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $# != 1  ||  $1 != "first" && $1 != "second" ]]
then
    echo "Error: Usage: $0 [first|second]"
    exit 1
fi
```

Or if you really wanted to use `csh` then you have re-write the code to:

```
#!/bin/csh
if ( $#argv != 1  ||  $1 != "first" && $1 != "second" ) then
    echo "Error: Usage: $0 [first|second]"
    exit 1
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use C-shell you should write

```
#!/bin/csh
if( $# != 1  ||  $1 != "first" && $1 != "second" ) then
    echo "Error: Usage: $0 [first|second]"
    exit 1
endif
```

Your version works for Bourne-like shells like `sh`, `bash` etc.